# C++ Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int *' for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, error-handling, compiler-errors

okay I literally have no idea what this error means. The * is for pointers right? I'm not using pointers so I don't understand what is happening? This is for my second programming class so I am quite new still. Any help would be much appreciated!!

**MAIN.CPP**

```c
#include <iostream>
#include "arr.hpp"
    
int main()
{
    int size = getInteger();
    int array;
    
    fillArray(array,size);
    sortArray(array, size);         //THE ERROR COMES UP FOR ALL OF THESE FUNCTIONS. 
    displayArray(array, size);
    binSearch(array, size, value);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**ARR.CPP**

```c
#include "arr.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int getInteger()
{
    int value;
    std::cout << "Please enter integer between 10 and 20 for size of array: ";
    std::cin >> value;
    // check if size is in range
    if (value >= 10 && value <= 20)
    {
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error. Please enter a correct value." << std::endl << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear(); //clears error from cin.fail()
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //removes old cin input for value
        std::cin >> value;
    }
    return value;
}

void fillArray(int array[], int size)
{
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(0)));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       array[i] = (std::rand() % 99)+1;
    }
}

void sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
    std::sort(array, array+size);
}

void displayArray(int array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
        if((i+1)%5 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

bool binSearch(int array[], int size, int value)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = size - 1;
    int mid;
    
    while(low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low+high) / 2;
        if(value == array[mid])
        {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (value > array[mid])
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**ARR.HPP**

```c
#ifndef arr_hpp

#define arr_hpp

int getInteger();

void fillArray(int array[], int size);

void sortArray(int array[], int size);

void displayArray(int array[], int size);

bool binSearch(int array[], int size, int value);

#endif /* arr_hpp */
```

Comment: Your functions are expecting you to pass an array. You're passing a single int. An array decays to a pointer when passed to a function so that is what the error shows.

Comment: Also, the code as posted is barely readable.   I suggest editing the post to make it somewhat readable.    On this site, the onus is on the poster to make their questions readable, the onus is not on others to wade through an unreadable post.

Comment: `I'm not using pointers` But you are! I know it's surprising but you cannot have an array as a function parameter in C++. In this code `void fillArray(int array[], int size);` `array` is actually a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are declaring `array` as an integer, instead of an array. I presume you want to declare an array of size `size` and pass it to the function.
2. You're missing the declaration of `value`.

To fix it, replace the declaration of `array` and declare `value`:

```
int size = getInteger();
int array[size];
int value;
...
```

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments, the above suggestion is not legal in standard C++. For your program to compile with legal C++, you might have a couple of choices:

1. Make `size` known at compile-time, e.g. 100, and ask the user to input a number between 0 and 100.
2. Use a data structure, like an `std::vector` and modify all function definitions accordingly.

Comment: `int array[size];` Variable sized arrays are not legal in C++. Where it works it's a compiler extension.

Comment: You are right, I compiled with the ISO C++11 compiler plus GNU extensions. If compiling manually, use the flag -std=gnu++11.

Comment: That works if you use gcc or other compilers that support a similar extension. But it is compiler specific, and that should be noted into the answer, not as a comment. OP's question was not about any specific compiler in particular.